# How to switch Python versions in mac terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-module, python-venv

I want to install ***pyaudio*** on python 3.8 but after reading a lot, I found out that it is best to use python 3.6. Now to install pyaudio, I want to install it on python 3.6 on my terminal but whenever I type `python --version`, it shows this `Python 2.7.16` version.
How can I do the change?

P.S. - I use pycharm to write the code.

Comment: What you see on doing `python3 --version` ?

Comment: i seePython 3.8.2

Comment: you should start using virtual environments to manage your different python versions and their libraries. Indeed, different projects should use different environments

Answer (score 0):

To manage different python installations on your machine you should use `pyenv`. From there in case you want to keep libraries confined to single project only you can use `virtual environments`.

References

- https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use `python3.6 --version` if you have it installed, it should give you `Python 3.6.x`. If you're trying to install pyaudio with Python 3.6 (I assume with pip), you can use `pip3.6 ...`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was finally able to install it :)